# How to add submenu items to the Windows Explorer context menu?

Tags: windows, user-interface, windows-shell

I can create a menu item in the Windows Explorer context menu by adding keys in the registry to **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell**.

How can I create submenu items to the just created menu item?

Comment: I can recommend this Answer to a related question in the SU forum: https://superuser.com/a/1302200/543612. It contains a link to a blog which helped me solve adding sub-menu items to the Context Menu: https://blog.sverrirs.com/2014/05/creating-cascading-menu-items-in.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe anything non-trival you'll have to create a [Context Menu Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776881.aspx).

You'll have to create a COM object that will create the menus and carry out the commands as they're clicked. I've only done this using C++ and COM. I'm not sure if there are easier ways to do this.

Comment: In Windows 10 it is possible to create a hierarchy of menus in the Context Menu using nested Keys in the Registry including: sub-menus, dividers, commands to run, icons. See https://blog.sverrirs.com/2014/05/creating-cascading-menu-items-in.html.

Answer (score 3):

Use SubCommands
    "SubCommands"="[NameOfMenu]"

Example for creating submenu for .TS files:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ts\shell\Encoding]
"MUIVerb"="Encoding video"
"SubCommands"="Encodex265Fade;EncodeTS2;watched"
"icon"="imageres.dll,-149"
"Position"=-
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"
"NeverDefault"=""
;"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Encode\\Fadein"
;"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CloudMe\\CloudMe\\favicon.ico"
```

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127431(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It seems relatively simple, but what are these "SubCommands" exactly? I mean... Where am I creating those? I am having the same problem with "ExtendedSubCommandsKey", I don't understand what it is referring to...

Comment: Not sure what version of Windows this answer refers to, but on Windows 10 I had to add an empty `SubCommands` string under the top level menu item. See https://superuser.com/a/1302200/543612.