# How to add subfolders to the Context Menu by hand with registry

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu

I have 2 programs and i want to add a folder with 2 subfolders to the right click menu on a file (Context Menu), so, when i press on a file, it shows me the name of the folder. When i move the cursor onto the folder, it should show the 2 subfolders (for 2 programs that i made that change size of this file.

MY PROBLEM: I don't know how to tell the registry that the folder (called MyPrograms, see below) has 2 subfolders.

IMPORTANT: I do NOT want to use software like Easy Context Menu.

[image]
This is how it looks so far.

When i press right click on a file, it looks like this:

You see that the last option has an arrow, i want the same, so subfolders.

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi46R.png)

The Values of my Keys are the following[image]

[image]

[image]

This now looks a bit weird.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add submenu items to the Windows Explorer context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734/how-to-add-submenu-items-to-the-windows-explorer-context-menu)

Comment: Not really, i once had what i wanted, i think its just a value that i need to add or another path where i need to put the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add this "SubCommands":
[image]

Now there is an arrow.